# secure open source Payment Gateway

Tags: security, payments

I'm working on an open source multi coin payment gateway.
`ETH`, `EOS`, `BTC` and `BCH` will be supported.

My plan so far:

The nodejs API runs on DigitalOcean. You send a `GET request` with your preferred `coin` and e.g. `price in USD`. It will send you back the `Pub key` to send the funds to, `price in crypto` and a unique memo used in the frontend: `txTransfer.data = Utils.toHex('my memo);

Web3.js on the server checks 15min for incoming transactions that are >= than the inquired price with the specific memo.

If successful, return status 200.

Did I forget something? Of course I will check my ports and not run the API as root, but is there anything else I can do so no one hacks into the server and steals all the coins?

The beginning: https://github.com/MarcelBlockchain/crypto-payment-gateway